# how to alternate colours in two diferent texts in a LazyColumn column Text

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-list

how to alternate colours in two diferent texts in a LazyColumn column Text. Follow the code below

```
 LazyColumn(/*contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp),*/
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                items(50) {index ->
                            Text("R$ 120,00/UN", fontSize = 13.sp,
                                    color = if(selectd==index) colorResource(id = R.color.red)
                                    else colorResource(id = R.color.white),
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .border(1.dp, Color.LightGray, RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
                                        .background(if(selectd==index) colorResource(id = R.color.pastel_green)
                                        else colorResource(id = R.color.cinza))
                                        .padding(5.dp)
                                        .clickable { selectd=index})

                            Text("R$ 120,00/KG", fontSize = 13.sp,
                                    color = if(selectd==index) colorResource(id = R.color.red)
                                    else colorResource(id = R.color.white),
                                    modifier = Modifier.border(1.dp, Color.LightGray, RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
                                        .background(if(selectd==index) colorResource(id = R.color.pastel_green)
                                        else colorResource(id = R.color.cinza))
                                        .padding(5.dp)
                                        .clickable { selectd=index})
                          }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itemsIndexed` instead of `index`.
Something like:

```
val itemsList = (0..12).toList()

LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    itemsIndexed(itemsList) { index, item ->

        val backgroundColor = if (selectd == index) Color.Blue 
             else{
                 if (index % 2 == 0) Color.Yellow else Color.Red
             }

        Text("R$ 120,00/UN", fontSize = 13.sp,
            modifier = Modifier
                .border(1.dp, Color.LightGray, RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
                .background(backgroundColor)
                .padding(5.dp)
                .clickable { selectd=index})
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: when you click you have to change the colors

Comment: @RafaelSouza just change val backgroundColor as you prefer. Check the updated answer.